# Is there any problem if I setup development environment in Centos and then migrate to RHEL?

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

What I'm trying to say is I have this project which developing system using PHP and I want to setup development environment in CentOS. Later if I migrate to RHEL, will there be any issue/problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be *slightly* more specific of what you are thinking of? What do you mean with "developing system" in particular and detail?

Comment: I'm going to leave this one open, but I agree with @planetmaker that you would do well to include a few more details.

Answer (score 2):

You should have no problems migrating from CentOS to RHEL. Back in the days CentOS was claiming that it is an operating system binary compatible with RHEL. I do not see that claim any more but still they are very close. CentOS is built on the same sources as RHEL. CentOS group replaces copyrighted material like RHEL logos, etc.

A program compiled on CentOS should work without changes on RHEL with the same version. If you transfer sources and compile it on RHEL, it might be even better.

Even if you migrate from CentOS to Ubuntu or any other linux, you should be able to build your project eventually on a new OS. It might require more changes. However, from CentOS to RHEL it should be done without changes on the project.

---

Now, I see, that you are working in PHP. For, PHP portability is even less problematic. You just have to make sure you have all the additional libraries for PHP, you might be using.

Comment: CentOS ist still binary compatible. And it is now owned by RedHat.